# AS3 fails with "Error #2048: Security sandbox violation" while attempting to connect to C# server

Tags: actionscript-3, server

I have been all over the internet trying every single solution (including the posts on this site) to this issue with absolutely zero success.

My server is setup on playerio.com service and is running in C#
I can connect locally with no problems, but when I attempt to access it over the internet I get the error #2048

```
function handleConnect(client:Client):void
{
trace("Sucessfully connected to player.io");

            //Set developmentsever (Comment out to connect to your server     online)
            // client.multiplayer.developmentServer = "localhost:8184";
            // client.multiplayer.developmentServer = "127.0.0.1:8184";
            client.multiplayer.developmentServer = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8184"; // "x" is equal to my server IP

        //Create pr join the room test
        client.multiplayer.createJoinRoom(
            "test",                             
            "MyCode",                           
            true,                               
            {},                                  
            {},                                 
            handleJoin,                         
            handleError                         
            );
    }
```

I am 99% sure this is an AS3 issue and not an issue with my server as I am able to connect to the server with other clients that are not AS3 related.

Comment: It is a security error. Simply put, if you want to connect to anything but the current SWF domain (over HTTP connection or TCP socket), the **endpoint** must explicitly allow you to do so. You can start learning the crossdomain security basics from here: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

Comment: problem is that the swf is not on any domain, its being loaded locally by the system its on

Comment: I don't advise such a setup for any purposes other than testing. Then, for testing purposes you should add that folder to the list of trusted locations: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: That was the first thing I did, and it did not fix anything

Comment: Then we're back to security. You need to read about crossdomain policy and place it correctly.

Comment: turns out that it was an issue with playerio.com and not flash